# API for list of azure mobile service and list of API management

Tags: c#, azure, azure-mobile-services

Looking for SDK (c#) or API for managing azure services -

- Mobile apps
- API management.

Found API documentation for azure cloud service [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee460781.aspx) but not for above 2 services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were in the right place.

API Management is here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn776326.aspx

Mobile Apps is just a Web App underneath - Web Apps / Mobile Apps / App Service uses Azure Resource Manager.  A tutorial is here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-deploy-complex-application-predictably/ and you can find the .NET SDK information here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-manager-net-sdk/ (review the templated deployment section - the first tutorial creates a template)